# WPF Fullscreen issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fullscreen

this my nightmare , even with JavaFX . i can't deal with fullscreen applications . the application runs smoothly on fixed height and width . But when converting it to Fullscreen mode . everything got scrampled . please refer to the pics

this a fixed width and height windows
[image: Fixed Width and height]

[image]

same windows but after converting it to maxmizied

[image]

and here is my question . how i can take control of xaml code when dealing with fullscreen apps ? originally iam a backend developer . but sometimes i get some tasks regarding frontend . here is the code for the loginWindow.xaml

and here is the code for the dashboard

```
<UserControl x:Class="Stock_Managment.Windows.Dashboard"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_FINAL"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
>
    <Grid Height="Auto"
          Width="Auto"
          x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#aa4b6b" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#6b6b83" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#3b8d99" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="179*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="88*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="32,280,16,0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <materialDesign:Card Background="#FFFFE6B7"
                                 Foreground="Black"
                                 x:Name="tot_cd"
                                 materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth3"
                                 Padding="8"
                                 UniformCornerRadius="6"
                                 Grid.Column="4"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Grid.Row="4"
                                 Width="263"
                                 Margin="10,10,0,37">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />


                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionAccentButton}"
                            materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="True"
                            materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="0"
                            Content=""
                            FontSize="30"
                            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="a7a"
                            Margin="159,55,23,156"
                            x:Name="tot_all"
                            FontWeight="DemiBold"
                            FontFamily="Dosis"
                            Background="Cornsilk"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Grid.Row="3" />
                    <materialDesign:Chip Margin="14,0,0,240"
                                         Width="210"
                                         FontStretch="Expanded"
                                         FontSize="25"
                                         Content="        Overview"
                                         FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                         FontFamily="Dosis"
                                         Foreground="White"
                                         Background="#FFB67B2D"
                                         Grid.RowSpan="4"
                                         Height="Auto" />
                    <Image Source="seven-star_logo-1.png"
                           Margin="-12,42,164,151"
                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.545,0.435"
                           Grid.Row="3" />
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         x:Name="tot_d"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         Height="30"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         IconBackground="AntiqueWhite"
                                         Width="226"
                                         Margin="14,136,7,111"
                                         Grid.Row="3">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Location" Foreground="Black" Height="31" Width="25" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         x:Name="tot_c"
                                         Height="Auto"
                                         Width="226"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         Margin="14,180,0,65"
                                         IconBackground="DimGray"
                                         Grid.Row="3">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Cctv" Foreground="White" Height="32" Width="30" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         x:Name="tot_s"
                                         Height="Auto"
                                         Width="226"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         Margin="14,232,0,10"
                                         IconBackground="White"
                                         Grid.Row="3">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="SimCard" Foreground="Black" Height="31" Width="28" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>

                </Grid>
            </materialDesign:Card>
            <materialDesign:Card Background="Wheat"
                                 Foreground="Black"
                                 materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth3"
                                 Padding="8"
                                 x:Name="wh_cd"
                                 UniformCornerRadius="6"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Grid.Row="4"
                                 Width="233"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                 Margin="20,10,0,37">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />


                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <materialDesign:Chip Margin="0,0,0,239"
                                         Width="210"
                                         FontStretch="Expanded"
                                         FontSize="25"
                                         Content="        Warehouse"
                                         FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                         FontFamily="Dosis"
                                         Foreground="White"
                                         Background="#FFB67B2D"
                                         Grid.RowSpan="4"
                                         Height="Auto" />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionAccentButton}"
                            materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="True"
                            materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="40"
                            Content=""
                            FontSize="30"
                            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="a7a"
                            Margin="149,55,10,164"
                            x:Name="perc_wh"
                            FontWeight="DemiBold"
                            FontFamily="Dosis"
                            Background="Cornsilk"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Grid.Row="3" />
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Warehouse"
                                             Grid.Row="3"
                                             Height="107"
                                             Width="72"
                                             Margin="0,23,0,0" />
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         Height="32"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         IconBackground="AntiqueWhite"
                                         Width="210"
                                         x:Name="wh_d"
                                         Margin="0,124,7,121"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         Click="wh_d_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Location" Foreground="Black" Height="31" Width="25" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>

                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         Height="Auto"
                                         Width="210"
                                         x:Name="wh_c"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         Margin="0,179,0,68"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         IconBackground="DimGray"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         Click="wh_c_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Cctv" Foreground="White" Height="32" Width="30" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         Height="Auto"
                                         x:Name="wh_s"
                                         Width="210"
                                         Margin="0,237,0,10"
                                         IconBackground="AliceBlue"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         Click="wh_s_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="SimCard" Foreground="Black" Height="31" Width="28" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                </Grid>
            </materialDesign:Card>
            <materialDesign:Card Background="Wheat"
                                 Foreground="Black"
                                 x:Name="cr_cd"
                                 materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth3"
                                 Padding="8"
                                 UniformCornerRadius="6"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Width="226"
                                 Margin="20,10,0,37">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />


                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionAccentButton}"
                            materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="True"
                            materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="40"
                            Content=""
                            FontSize="30"
                            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="a7a"
                            Margin="143,55,10,165"
                            x:Name="perc_cr"
                            FontWeight="DemiBold"
                            FontFamily="Dosis"
                            Background="Cornsilk"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Grid.Row="3" />
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ApplicationExport"
                                             Grid.Row="3"
                                             Height="107"
                                             Width="72"
                                             Margin="0,23,0,0" />
                    <materialDesign:Chip Margin="0,0,0,239"
                                         Width="210"
                                         FontStretch="Expanded"
                                         FontSize="25"
                                         Content="      ControlRoom"
                                         FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                         FontFamily="Dosis"
                                         Foreground="White"
                                         Background="#FFB67B2D"
                                         Grid.RowSpan="4"
                                         Height="Auto" />
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         x:Name="con_d"
                                         IconBackground="AntiqueWhite"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         Height="36"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         Width="210"
                                         Margin="0,130,0,111"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         Click="con_d_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Location" Foreground="Black" Height="31" Width="25" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         Height="36"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         x:Name="con_c"
                                         Width="210"
                                         Margin="0,182,0,59"
                                         IconBackground="DimGray"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         Click="con_c_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Cctv" Foreground="White" Height="32" Width="30" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         x:Name="con_s"
                                         Height="36"
                                         Width="210"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         Margin="0,231,0,10"
                                         IconBackground="AliceBlue"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         Click="con_s_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="SimCard" Foreground="Black" Height="31" Width="28" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                </Grid>
            </materialDesign:Card>
            <materialDesign:Card Background="Wheat"
                                 Foreground="Black"
                                 x:Name="emp_cd"
                                 materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth3"
                                 Padding="8"
                                 UniformCornerRadius="6"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Width="220"
                                 Margin="20,10,0,37">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />


                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionAccentButton}"
                            materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="True"
                            materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="40"
                            Content=""
                            FontSize="30"
                            materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="a7a"
                            Margin="137,55,10,166"
                            x:Name="perc_emp"
                            FontWeight="DemiBold"
                            FontFamily="Dosis"
                            Background="Cornsilk"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Grid.Row="3" />
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Person"
                                             Grid.Row="3"
                                             Height="107"
                                             Width="72"
                                             Margin="0,23,0,0" />
                    <materialDesign:Chip Margin="0,0,0,239"
                                         Width="210"
                                         FontStretch="Expanded"
                                         FontSize="25"
                                         Content="        Employees"
                                         FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                         FontFamily="Dosis"
                                         Foreground="White"
                                         Background="#FFB67B2D"
                                         Grid.RowSpan="4"
                                         Height="Auto" />
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         IconBackground="AntiqueWhite"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         Height="36"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         Width="210"
                                         x:Name="emp_d"
                                         Margin="0,130,-6,111"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         Click="emp_d_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Location" Foreground="Black" Height="31" Width="25" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         Height="36"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         Width="204"
                                         x:Name="emp_c"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         Margin="0,179,0,62"
                                         IconBackground="DimGray"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         Click="emp_c_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Cctv" Foreground="White" Height="31" Width="25" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                    <materialDesign:Chip Content=""
                                         Height="36"
                                         FontWeight="Bold"
                                         x:Name="emp_s"
                                         Width="204"
                                         Margin="0,231,0,10"
                                         IconBackground="AliceBlue"
                                         Grid.Row="3"
                                         ToolTip="Press for more info"
                                         Click="emp_s_Click">
                        <materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="SimCard" Foreground="Black" Height="31" Width="28" />
                        </materialDesign:Chip.Icon>
                    </materialDesign:Chip>
                </Grid>
            </materialDesign:Card>

        </StackPanel>
        <Label FontSize="25" Foreground="AliceBlue" Content="Stock In Chart" Margin="454,9,0,564" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Label>
        <lvc:CartesianChart Background="Beige" Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="38,47,17,345" >
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis Title="New Equipments" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="Days" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
        <ProgressBar
    
            IsIndeterminate="False" Margin="0,0,0,611" Height="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What i have tried . i tried searching on internet . i tried prevent using the grid and replace it by stackpanels . but no hope

Comment: OMG your XAML code is a mess! You are using margins to position your Controls. You have also width and height set certain sizes. Thats not an easy task to sort it out... Honestly. Thats a day job. Sorry mate.

Comment: @LegacyCode  i know you are right . Actually this my task .  I need to fix that mess but i don't know from where to start

Comment: Delete everything... Start from scratch... You can also try to remove margins, widths and heights first and see how it looks after that.

Comment: If you need a quick fix fast then put a Viewbox around everything and give that parent Grid a width and height that matches whatever dimensions it was designed for. That will cause the whole page to scale in response to window resizing, which may or may not be desirable, but it will at least keep it looking presentable while you work on fixing it properly.